# Need to keep an element within a row visible on resize. Alternative to setTimeout?

Tags: react-virtualized

Our project involves showing a document on-screen. We use `react-virtualized` to display that document, where we might have text like this:

```
------ Row 1 ------
<div id="abc">Some text<div>
<div id="def">Some more text</div>

------ Row 2 ------
<div id="ghi">Some text<div>
<div id="jkl">Some more text</div>  <---- Keep this element in center of screen

------ Row 3 ------
...
```

We want to ensure that a given element (e.g. `id="jkl"`)  will **stay in the center of the screen**.

Unfortunately, the user can resize the window, which causes the feedback element to move away from the center of the screen.

### Our Solution

To over-simplify, our solution is:

1. On resize, call `elem.scrollIntoView()`

### The Problem

The underlying `<List>` component sometimes finishes rendering **after** `elem.scrollIntoView()` has already succeeded. So the element ends up moving up or down from the center of the page again.

---

Our best remedy for that at the moment is essentially just `setTimeout(() => elem.scrollIntoView(), 10)`.

But `setTimeout` is terrible. Is there some kind of callback we can use instead to avoid using `setTimeout`?

That "dream callback" would be `onCompletionOfRenderTriggeredByResize()`. Does something like that exist?

Here is a CodeSandbox link (only works in Chrome):

[image: Edit react-virtualized List with width 100%]